# any way to use super+scroll up for changing the workspace in Xorg like wayland?

Tags: linux, fedora, xorg, wayland

super+scroll up not changing the workspace when using Xorg instead of wayland.
anyway to fix/change?
*need to use Xorg as wayland don't allow to cast full screen normally. If there's a way to cast full screen in wayland, please suggest.

**System** : gnome41 - fedora35

Comment: I am using Xorg for the same reason on one Fedora system but scroll up/down works normally.  Are there any error messages, etc., when you try?

Comment: @rickhg12hs , no scroll up/down is just fine, im talking about super + up/down. In wayland, using it directly scroll between workspaces. But in Xorg, it first preview the apps of current workspace, then scroll (not smoothly/directly/timing of scrolling up-down is also need to be bit delayed).

Comment: You are using [`gnome`](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-keyboard-shortcuts.html.en), yes?  Which up/down do you mean? ... arrow up/down?  page up/down?

Comment: @rickhg12hs i meant mouse scrolling.

Comment: For both my Wayland and Xorg, if I first press then release Master, I can scroll up/down through the workspaces. Are you looking for some other behavior?

Comment: Exactly, but you dont need to release Super in wayland, scrolling and pressing super at the same time is just enough to switch workspace in wayland, which Xorg does not offer. I found some blogs releated to this but they just suggested to switch to wayland from Xorg.

Comment: Maybe I don't have the most recent version of Wayland, but for me Wayland and Xorg behave the same.